# sankey plot R not displaying markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, sankey-diagram, networkd3

I'm working on an R markdown document but am stuck with a "sankey chart" element. The Sankey element works fine in its code, but when I knit markdown the element doesn't show up in the markdown (or is just blank[?]).

Migration flow

```
library(networkD3)

# creating the df    
uni_reenrolled <- c("CBS","KU", "DTU","RUC", "AU", "ITU", "AAU", "SDU", "DTU",
                    "KU", "SDU", "CBS", "AAU", "RUC", "ITU", "AU", "KU", "ITU",
                    "CBS", "DTU", "SDU", "KU", "CBS", "DTU", "RUC", "SDU", "AU",
                    "AAU", "ITU", "KU", "SDU", "CBS", "RUC", "AU", "AAU", "DTU",
                    "ITU", "SDU", "KU", "AU", "AAU", "RUC", "DTU", "CBS", "ITU",
                    "AAU", "AU", "KU", "SDU", "DTU", "CBS", "RUC", "ITU", "AU", 
                    "AAU", "SDU", "KU", "CBS", "RUC", "DTU", "ITU")

uni_dropout<- c("CBS","CBS", "CBS", "CBS", "CBS",  "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", 
                    "DTU", "DTU", "DTU", "DTU", "DTU", "DTU", "DTU", "DTU", 
                    "ITU", "ITU", "ITU", "ITU", "ITU", "KU", "KU", "KU", "KU", 
                    "KU", "KU", "KU", "KU", "RUC", "RUC", "RUC", "RUC", "RUC", 
                    "RUC", "RUC", "RUC", "SDU", "SDU", "SDU", "SDU", "SDU", 
                    "SDU", "SDU", "SDU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", 
                    "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AU", "AU", "AU", "AU", "AU", "AU",
                    "AU","AU")

dropout <- c(274, 272, 48, 40, 29, 27, 25, 22, 604, 275, 66, 53, 41, 29, 27, 23,
         27, 21, 16, 8, 6, 1093, 199, 175, 141, 129, 99, 78, 55, 147, 53, 44,
         27, 23, 18, 14, 12, 1254, 124, 99, 56, 45, 44, 28, 5, 939, 140, 85,
         69, 56, 27, 24, 8, 1810, 176, 166, 94, 34, 33, 21, 5)

sankey_uni_data <- data.frame(dropout, uni_reenrolled, uni_dropout)%>%
  mutate(uni_reenrolled = paste0(" ",uni_reenrolled ))

# creating the sankey-chart
node_names <- (c(as.character(unique(sankey_uni_data$uni_dropout)), unique(as.character(sankey_uni_data$uni_reenrolled))))
nodes <- data.frame(name = node_names)

links <- data.frame(source = match(sankey_uni_data$uni_dropout, node_names) - 1,
                    target = match(sankey_uni_data$uni_reenrolled, node_names) - 1,
                    value = sankey_uni_data$dropout)


sn <-sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source",
                   Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
                   units = "dropouts", fontSize = 25, nodeWidth = 30, 
                   fontFamily = "sans-serif", iterations = 0)
sn
```

When i'm running the code the diagram comes out just fine [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2z4j.png), but when i'm knit'ing it, it doesn't show, and just leaves the markdown-page blank.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you share your complete Rmarkdown file?

Comment: Please include the code to load the package: `library(networkD3)`. This will make the code in the question reproducible .

Comment: I've updated the code a bit... adding library and code improvment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. It was headlines -tabset, that was the problem. I edited them and that fixed it